# Convert Linq result into datatable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, datatable, crystal-reports

I have process that should show a report using Crystal Reports and in my project i used .NET MVC as my framework and Entity Framework for database models.

The  problem is i do not know how to send dataset into my report, as i know that crystal report supported datatable as their dataset, so i need to convert linq result into datatable, here is my code so far:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> SalesContractEntity = _db.Generate_Report(202, "RGBCtestcontract2");

ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
rd.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/") + "ColdLineBaliHolidayClubENUSD.rpt");
rd.SetDataSource(SalesContractEntity); 
CrystalReportViewerID.ReportSource = rd;
```

Note:

- i am using stored procedure for dataset
- there are lots of column which produces by that SP
- that code give me and error like this:

> System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult  to
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Comment: What is the return type of Generate_Report()? You likely need to explicitly construct a DataTable from it.

Comment: yes i just found the solution after a day searching :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found the solution

here is my code:

```
List<Generate_Report_Result> ReportList = new List<Generate_Report_Result>();
            ReportList = _db.Generate_Report(ApplicantID, ContractNumber).ToList();

            DataTable datanya = ToDataTable(ReportList);
            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
            string ThePath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/") + ReportFileName;
            rd.Load(ThePath);
            rd.SetDataSource(datanya);
            CrystalReportViewerID.ReportSource = rd;
            CrystalReportViewerID.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
            CrystalReportViewerID.RefreshReport();

private DataTable ToDataTable(List<Generate_Report_Result> items)
        {
            var tb = new DataTable(typeof(Generate_Report_Result).Name);

            PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(Generate_Report_Result).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                tb.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
            }

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                var values = new object[props.Length];
                for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }

                tb.Rows.Add(values);
            }

            return tb;
        }
```

and dont forget to add **aspnet_client** on our project folder (you can copy from C:\inetpub\wwwroot)